# How to stop a HTML5 video player when it enters the full screen mode on iOS / iPads?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, safari

I am trying to figure out how to pause an html5 video player when it enter the full screen mode in Iphone and ipad using javascript.

it seems that when it enters the full screen it goes to the native player and javascript can no longer control the playback ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple JavaScript Controller</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*--------------------------------------------------*/
        /* A Simple JavaScript Media Controller and Resizer */
        function playPause() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            if (myVideo.paused){
                myVideo.play();
            }else{
                myVideo.pause();
            }
        }
       function makeBig() {
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.height = myVideo.videoHeight * 2;
       }
       function makeNormal() {
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.height = myVideo.videoHeight;
       }

        /*-------------------------------------------*/
        /* Using DOM Events to Monitor Load Progress */
        function getPercentProg() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            var endBuf = myVideo.buffered.end(0);
            var soFar = parseInt(((endBuf / myVideo.duration) * 100));
            document.getElementById("loadStatus").innerHTML =  soFar + '%';
        }
       function myAutoPlay() {
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.play();
       }
       function addMyListeners(){
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.addEventListener('progress', getPercentProg, false);
           myVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', myAutoPlay, false);
       }

        /*----------------------------------------*/
        /* Replacing a Media Source Sequentially */
        function myNewSrc() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = "sample_iTunes.mov";
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
        }
        // add a listener function to the ended event
        function myAddListener(){            
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
            myVideo.addEventListener('progress', getPercentProg, false);
        }



        function timerStop() {
            setTimeout(function(){ playPause(); alert("PAUSED");}, 3000);
        }

    </script>

</head>

<!--<body onload="addMyListeners()">-->
<body onload="myAddListener()">

    <div class="video-player" align="center">
        <video controls>
            <!--<source src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->
            <source src="sample_iPod.m4v">
            Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
        </video>

        <p id="loadStatus">...</p>

        <p>
            <a href="javascript:playPause(); timerStop();">Play/Pause</a> |
            <a href="javascript:makeBig();">2x Size</a> |
            <a href="javascript:makeNormal();">1x Size</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> > Note: the above code seems to work fine on Chrome and Ipad safari (non native player). >>> But it wont work on iphones (as it loads the native player automatic).

Comment: Do the orientation changes in the full screen mode?

Comment: no. Just need to pause the video playback while in fullscreen more(native mode). thanks

Answer (score 0):

you timerStop function has a typos; You didn't call palyPuased function. It should be playPause();

```
  function timerStop() {
      setTimeout(function(){ playPause(); alert("PAUSED");}, 3000);
  }
```

Comment: user1577263, thank you for noticing it . Still doesn't solve the problem. Only thing it does is to stop the time line. but the playback continues to play

Comment: This is my steps to stop play:1:click  play/pause,2:enter full screen, 3:wating 3s, Alert window is shown, video is stoped;

Comment: Append timerStop() after the playPause() on Play/Pause tag may produce conflict situation.

Comment: Not even the Alert window is get shown. It seems that once in native mode, no js can run

Comment: I test this in desktop chrome, and ipad Safri. I once created a application using custome video control bar. I hide the native vidoe control bar. Only using a custom UI to control the video tag;.

Comment: Sorry. I should had said. On Chrome and ipad non native player it works. But the problem is on iphone - it wont work. thank you